# Translate tool or extension for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, translation

OS: windows XP SP3

For: Google Chrome

Is there translate tool/extension that can translate word or look up dictionary?

Desired features:

- a keyboard shortcut to toggle translation, so it might be mouse over the word or select the word and press for example F2 key to pop the translation.
- (optional) the translation should shows in a bubble window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [bubble-translate](http://code.google.com/p/bubble-translate/) to see if it does what you need.

Comment: This is good, but I was wondering if it could also display dictionary part not just translation part. Or would there be other tool can achieve this.

Comment: Not sure. There is a google dictionary extension but that doesn't really work for translation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[Lingoes](http://www.lingoes.net/) does exactly what you want.  Just need to find and load your target language dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

[Ddict](http://ddict.me) is exactly what you want, a google extension